# Issues with my layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i have split my view to 5 times and i would like to put different things on each compartment. Here is the problem i am facing;

Without text view[image]

With a textview
[image]

Here's my code;

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#add823"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#111111"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Power"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: Change your second `LinearLayout` width from `wrap_content` to `0dp`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you xml like this Instead of `wrap_content` use `0dp` for `LinearLayout` (parent of Power text)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#add823"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#111111"></View>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Power"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change **wrapcontent** to **0dip** in layout contain **Power text**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#add823"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#111111"></View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Power" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And result:

[image]